# How do I solve my layouts being messed up due to fields_with_error in RoR app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm using Fomantic(Semantic) UI in my Ruby on Rails, and I realize my forms get messed up when validations fail because of the fields_with_errors class that's automatically added. Is there a known fix for this?

Prior to submission, my form looks like this

[image]

After a failed submission, where nothing is entered in any of the field, it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I use the following code inside `config/application.rb`

```
    config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
      %Q(<div class="field error">#{html_tag}</div>).html_safe
    end
```

This code uses semantic way of indication of fields in error state. You can further customise this setting to your needs, see rails [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-view) for details.
Next important point is an extra check on your form tag to add semantic `ui form error` class, something like:

```
form_for(@model, html: {class: @model.errors.any? ? 'ui form error' : 'ui form'}) do |f|
```

This will show error messages if you use them.